# How to validate the child component NgForms having 3 different NgForm from the parent component in Angular4

Tags: forms, angular, angular2-forms

I have a scenario where I am accessing two different NgForms one within Parent form #parentform and other in the Child component #childForm & #childForm1, and i want to check the validity of the controls of child form wether valid or not in parent component form. How to do this in angular4.

I also followed this link:
[Check if a form is valid from a parent component using Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44943981/check-if-a-form-is-valid-from-a-parent-component-using-angular-4)

everytime i am getting undefined for the reference of child component form.

My code is something like this.

parent.component.html

```
    <form class="form-wrapper" (ngSubmit)="parentForm.form.valid && save()" #parentForm="ngForm" novalidate>
        <input id="firstName" type="text" placeholder="" class="validate" name="firstName" [(ngModel)]="firstname_" #firstName="ngModel"                         required>
    </form>
    <child-component></child-component>
```

child.component.html

```
  <form class="form-wrapper" (ngSubmit)="childForm.form.valid && save()" #childForm="ngForm" novalidate>
            <input id="phoneNumber" type="text" placeholder="" class="validate" name="phoneNumber" [(ngModel)]="phone_" #phoneNumber="ngModel"                       required>
 </form>

 <form class="form-wrapper" (ngSubmit)="childForm1.form.valid && save()" #childForm1="ngForm" novalidate>
            <input id="mobileNumber" type="text" placeholder="" class="validate" name="mobileNumber" [(ngModel)]="mobile_" #mobileNumber="ngModel" required>
 </form>
```

Now i want to validate the child component form "childForm" & "childForm1" valid or not in parent form.

Same is reproduced at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cjorjz...

Comment: @yurzui posted question here....

Comment: What you can try is something with the **@Input** of the child something like `<child-component [parent]="parentForm.form.valid"></child-component>` . And in the child catch it with `ngOnChanges(changes: any) {`

Comment: I am not getting it. Can you narrate with stackblitz ??

Comment: Tested it and put my answer. The stackblitz couldn't be edited and saved...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what you want, is to pass the `parentForm.form.status` to the child with an **@Input()**.

In parent html:

```
<child-component [parent]="parentForm.form.status"></child-component>
```

Then in your child:

```
@Input() parent: any;
private boolean: boolean = false;

ngOnChanges(changes: any) {
  if(changes.dataSet.currentValue === 'VALID'){
    this.boolean = true;
  }
  else { this.boolean = false; }
}
```

And to check it `console.log(this.boolean)` it or put `{{boolean}}` in html. Or `childForm.form.valid && save() && boolean` in html.

**EDIT**

To send the validation back:

In the child component you have to tigger the @Output() so use a change event on the html:

```
@Output valid: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

private checkValid(_childForm: string){
  if(_childForm === 'VALID'){
    this.valid.emit(true);
  }
  else { this.valid.emit(false);
}
```

In html to all your child formsfield:

```
(ngModelChange)="checkValid(childForm.form.status)"
```

In your parent html:

```
<child-component [parent]="parentForm.form.status" (valid)="setValidChild($event)"></child-component>
```

In the parent component:

```
private childBoolean: boolean= false;

private setValidChild(_boolean: boolean){
  this.childBoolean = _boolean;
}
```

Comment: Great Solution it works... but what i want is vice a versa of the solution you posted. I want to validate the child form in the Parent component... that too multiple child forms...

Comment: But found one issue.. When i am refreshing the page i am not getting the reference to child component showing blank ....

Comment: Cause a refresh will empty everything then you have to add `localStorage`. But that's a whole different question ;)

Comment: So how to handle now ??

Comment: Make a new stackoverflow question and post your question ;)

Comment: Thanks for help @Swoox. I am able to handle that. Thank you